# In DB2 SELECT MOST Frequent occurrence and link with other table

Tags: sql, db2, jupyter

I have two table `Census` and `Crime`

From the `crime` table, i need to find the most frequent occurrence of `community_area_number`
and linked the `crime`'s `community_area_number` to table `census`'s `community_area_number` to get the `community_area_name`

I am able to do the first step, but i fail at linking to another table. Please advise where have I done wrong. Thanks

```
%%sql
SELECT COUNT(CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER) AS MOST_FREQ, CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, CE.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME from CRIME AS CR, CENSUS AS CE 

WHERE CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER = CE.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER
GROUP BY CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER 
ORDER BY COUNT(CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER) DESC LIMIT 1
```

***Expected output***

**MOST_FREQ ,community_area_number,, COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME**

```
      43                25                     Uptown
```

**Sample CENSUS**

[image]

SAMPLE CRIME
[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, it is a SQL question

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help your question.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have added

Answer (score 1):

You should be writing the query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS MOST_FREQ, 
       CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, CE.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME 
FROM CRIME CR JOIN
     CENSUS CE 
     ON CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER = CE.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER
GROUP BY CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, CE.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note the use of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

The relevant change, though, is to include `CE.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME` in the `GROUP BY`.  All non-aggregated columns should be in the `GROUP BY` as a general rule.

Also, `COUNT(*)` is simpler for counting matches, so this query uses that instead of counting the non-`NULL` values of a column.

Comment: Thanks this works. Haven't learn on JOIN. Will read up on in. Thanks for making it reable.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a aggregate function `COUNT(CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER) AS MOST_FREQ`
and all other (non aggregate) return values need to be in the GROUP BY clause.

For your query it means try adding `E.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME` to the GROUP BY.

Comment: After adding `CE.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME` to GROUP BY, i have following error `A reference to column "COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER" is ambiguous`

Comment: you have to qualfy the column - prefixing it with CE. or CR. referencing the table you want to draw it from